# Scala Recursively Count Elements Given Predicate

Tags: scala, recursion

I have this iterative function which counts the number of Boolean values in a list.

```
def countBoolIter[A](test: A=>Boolean, a: List[A]) = {
    var count = 0
    for(elem <- a){
        if(test(elem)) count += 1
    }
    count
}
```

The first parameter passed in is an `isBool` function:

```
def isBool(i: Any) = i match {
    case _: Boolean => true
    case _    => false
}
```

Calling the function looks like this:

```
countBoolIter(isBool, List(1, true, 3, true, false, "hi"))
// Output: 3
```

**Now**, I tried converting it into a *tail recursive* function like this:

```
def countBoolRec[A](test: A=>Boolean, a: List[A], acc: Int = 0): Int = a match {
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t if(test(h)) => countBoolRec(test, a, acc+1)
    case h :: t => countBoolRec(test, a, acc)
}
```

However, I'm getting a runtime error because the function doesn't return anything; no errors are thrown. I presume that it is stuck in an infinite loop that's why nothing is being returned.

**Question:** How should I fix my attempted recursive implementation?

Comment: "How should I fix my attempted recursive implementation?" This is one of those problems that would have been trivially solvable by stepping through in a debugger. Do people not use debuggers nowadays? And get off my lawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the function countBoolRec:

```
    @tailrec
    def countBoolRec[A](test: A=>Boolean, a: List[A], acc: Int = 0): Int = a match {
        case Nil => acc
        case h :: t if(test(h)) => countBoolRec(test, t, acc+1)
        case h :: t => countBoolRec(test, t, acc)
    }
```

In the recursive call, use t as the parameter and no again a. If not, basically, you are in an infinite loop.

Also, better to use the @tailrec annotation to be sure that the implementation is "tail recursive".

Answer (score 1):

You're repeatedly recursing with the same list as input.

Consider the case where a.head passes the test:

countBoolRec(test, a, 0)
countBoolRec(test, a, 1)
countBoolRec(test, a, 2)
... and so on

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec // Not that your original code wasn't tail-recursive, but it's a generally good practice to mark code that isn't tail recursive with this annotation
def countBoolRec[A](test: A=>Boolean, a: List[A], acc: Int = 0): Int = a match {
  case Nil => acc
  case h :: t if (test(h)) => countBoolRec(test, t, acc + 1)
  case h :: t => countBoolRec(test, t, acc)
}
```

Though you could also just as well write:

```
(0 /: a) { (acc, v) => acc + (if (test(v)) 1 else 0) }
```

Comment: Joke: The second option is ok if you are a cryptographer.